# How do I fill in the 'gaps' of missing data in Firestore or to make sure that it is complete?

Tags: database, list, google-cloud-firestore

Please pardon me for asking a noob question, or if my explanation is not clear. It is quite complicated for me and I have tried to make it as clear as possible. I'm open for any ideas to improve this question.

I'm working on Flutter App, with Cloud Firestore for the cloud database and Sembast DB for local database.

The scenario is like this:

Supposedly on June 14th I added 5 documents in a collection like this:

```
Bob,
Sally,
Hannah,
Jane,
Chris,
```

Then in the cloud there is also a document that keeps track of the latest update, which was June 14th.
Now, the App fetch the data with pagination of 3 documents each time. 
Thus for the first fetch, the APP gets documents: Bob, Sally, Hannah with latest update was June 14th 
Then the App saved these 3 documents and the latest updated date into its local DB.

Suppose the APP was offline for awhile after that. 
While it was offline, there were 5 new data added on June 16th:

```
Bobby,
Andy,
John,
Jack,
Danny,
```

Once the APP gets online again, it compare the latest data in cloud and local DB it will found that the latest updated date has changed to June 16th. Thus it will fetch 3 new documents from June 16th:
Bobby, Andy and John.

So now the local Database looks like this:

```
Bobby,
Andy,
John,
Bob,
Sally,
Hannah
```

You can see that there are some lost data in between which are `Jack` and `Danny`. 
Because they are at the middle of the list. 

 However, for `Jane` and `Chris`, the app would get it when it arrives at the end of the list, because then it can use `.startAfter` command in Firestore.

So the problem is for the data in the middle of the list such as `Jack` and `Danny`. Hence, how does the app knows that there are some missing data there?

What we hope to see is that when the app scrolls down, we hope the app is able to fill in the missing data and make it looks like this:

```
Bobby,
Andy,
John,
Jack,
Danny,
Bob,
Sally,
Hannah
```

This example only consist of 10 documents but in my real case I'm dealing with thousands of documents with tens and thousands of users. 
Checking documents on each 'gap' is not performance friendly.

Moreover, I must make sure that I have the least number of document read.

And for those who wants to see codes. Here is the code I use to fetch documents in Cloud Firestore:

```
Query query = collectionReference
              .orderBy('lastUpdated', descending: true)
              .startAfter([lastDocDateRetrieved])
              .limit(100);

// Getting the document based on the query.
querySnapshot = await query.getDocuments();
```

Explanation: This query will fetch the data in order of the lastUpdated Date in Cloud Firestore, which starts after the latest document's updated date recorded in local DB.

Then I save the data in local DB (Sembast DB):

```
// after converting the querySnapshot into two lists of keys and values:
await db.transaction((txn) async {
        // Save all documents in the local database
        await _store.records(keyList).put(txn, valueList);
});
```

The key problem is not in the code, but in the logic of how do we know that there are missing data in between documents?

Comment: Without seeing the code that queries Firestore, it's hard to imagine what you are actually doing here.  Please edit the question to be clear what your queries are, and what you observe from each one.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson I have added some codes for fetching data and storing it. However, the problem lies not on the code itself but on the logic of what happen in certain scenarios as described in the question. Does this makes sense? Let me know if I miss anything.. Thanks again.

Comment: Why don't you simply dump whatever is on the Local DB after it syncs with Firestore and repopulate it with a new fetch from scratch? This would eliminate the logic issues you've been facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) to cycle through documents from a query (using `startAfter()`), the API can **not** tell you if new documents were added in a page that you've already gone through.  If you want to know if new documents were added, you would have to start the query over from the beginning.

The only alternative to this (which I have never seen anyone do) is to set up individual listeners on each page query, and keep them all active so that the listener can tell you if something changed within that page.  Doing this correctly would require pretty large amount of code to handle all the boundary cases, and might be expensive if your documents change frequently.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand the complication and why people won't do that. So now I decided based on my situation that I will only paginate when the app update downward the list. But when the app update upward (to get latest data) it will not paginate. And if the last update is too old, we just delete the whole data and replace with the new one.